# vlookup in ethercalc acts weird

Tags: javascript, web, spreadsheet

I have a small ethercalc table (see https://www.ethercalc.org/6ucz5hse3q ) and want to use vlookup, but I get a #REF! Error. I can't see why.

In short: the table looks like:

```
Date       ||Value
01-Sep 2015||1
   ...
28-Sep 2015||28
```

This is just an example to produce the error.
What i did is:

```
=vlookup(today(), $A$2:$A$31, 3, 0)
```

Instead of getting the right number, I get a #REF! Error.
But if I set the column value to 1:

```
=vlookup(today(), $A$2:$A$31, 1, 0)
```

I get the correct date value.
What am I missing here? I would appreciate any suggestion.

thanks in advance
Hannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$2:$A$31 does not include the third column — changing it to $A$2:$C$31 (as I did on 6ucz5hse3q) would fix that.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the range only specifies the the values to check. Thanks a lot.